# Check special values from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to read a value from an element like this for ie

```
<div id="element" winner="first"></div>
```

So i can get the "first" value from winner?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you should use data attributes to store custom data:

```
<div id="element" data-winner="first"></div>
```

Now, you can use the `.data()` method:

```
$('#element').data('winner');  // "first"
```

If you can't use data attributes, you can use the `.attr()` method:

```
$('#element').attr('winner');  // "first"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var winner = $("#element").attr('winner');
```

If you have control over the markup, I would suggest not to make up your own attributes.  Instead, use HTML5 `data-*` attributes.